# Javascript pass by reference or value?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this question being asked multiple times but I have a specific example to clarify.

```
var a = {animal: 'cat'};

var b = a;

a.animal = 'bear';
```

Here, I see b.animal will give an output "bear". Why is that? And how do I retain the original reference "cat" for variable b?

Comment: You have copied a *reference* from `a` to `b`, but they both point *at the same object*. If you want to copy the object, then you need to copy each property of that object to a new object.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/522479

Comment: It's by-value, but the value is an object reference. So, `b` is a copy of `a`, but they both still refer to the same object. [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Javascript is always pass by value...1000 % sure

Comment: @Pilot and for an object the value is its reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [both refer to the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177162/javascript-pass-by-reference-or-value).

May be you are confused because in Javascript, you usually don't use the "new" keyword on built-in types, even if you can.

You could also declare "a" like this :

```
var a = new Object();
a.animal = "cat";
```

Now it is maybe more clear why "b" change when "a" change.

If you "b" have its own property then [you have to clone "a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object).

Answer (score 1):

You should clone the object instead of copying the reference (b = a);

here's a question where this problem is very well explained:
[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

'Primitives' are copied, objects are not (that is, the reference to it is copied). 
If you need to protect the property, define it `writeable:false` via `defineProperty`